# How strong are Terminators?

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series

Just how strong are Terminators?  Both T-800 and T-1000 units have been shown demonstrating feats of strength that are far in excess of human norms.  Is there any way that this strength can be quantified?  How much can they pull?  How much can they carry?

If possible, I'd prefer answers that would allow me to make a direct comparison to an elephant (i.e. could a T-800 or T-1000 be able to [carry](http://www.onekind.org/be_inspired/top_10_lists/strongest/) or [pull](http://www.elephantsforever.co.za/elephants-faq.html#.U9PkpvldWSo) more weight than an adult elephant?).

[image: A black and white picture which was edited to depict a scene in which young adult Arnold Schwarzenegger in underpants is pulling on the tail of an elephant. The presence of Arnold is to question how strong Terminators are, since he plays the role of T-800 robots in Terminator movies. The edited picture by itself is somewhat comedic, because even though Arnold is bent forward to pull on the tail of the elephant, he's still as tall as the beast.]

Comment: What in the world is the picture for? Are there people here who doesn't know what an elephant looks like?

Comment: Awesome pic, from where? @Bobby that's what it looks like when an 800 series model 101 terminator (Arnold) catches an elephant by the tail.

Comment: @BobbyAlexander - The picture was an original creation of mine, in honour of the trouble we had getting this question approved.

Comment: @Mazura - It's a composite image from a couple of sources.

Comment: Wow! Nice work, I'd of never known. @Richard

Comment: @Richard: Ok. But I don't think it helps the question in any way. I mean this is the same site where someone edited one of my questions to remove the words "Great movie, by the way" because it didn't add anything to the question.

Comment: @bobbyalexander - The ways of the site are mysterious indeed. I rarely find cause to refuse edits to my own answers.

Comment: Seven.  They are seven strong.

Answer (score 19):

Adult elephants can carry something like 500Kg [with their trunks](http://www.elephantsforever.co.za/elephants-faq.html#.U9DuME1OXIU) and approximately 9 tonnes [on their backs](http://www.southafrica.info/travel/wildlife/elephant-safaris.htm#.U9DuJ01OXIU) without suffering permanent injury.

In the video below we see a *T850 series Model 101 Terminator* carrying approximately 1 tonne of metal-lined coffin, weaponry and a full-grown man.

We also see a similar model terminator (temporarily) holding up a door that must weight at least 10 tonnes.

Based on this, a terminator is **at least as strong** as an elephant, probably more like twice as strong.

Comment: Technically speaking, that is a T-850 in those scenes.

Comment: @T-1000 - http://www.reactiongifs.us/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/technically_correct_futurama.gif

Comment: Just noting the terminator is carrying the coffin using only his should/arm strength. For humans these are considered weak muscle and bad leverage. If he'd doing deadlifts, he could lift so much more

Comment: Where did the estimate of 1 tonne come from?  Clearly the coffin doesn't weigh anything close to that or the terminator would tip over.

Comment: @Ward - I have based it on the assumption that John Connor weighs approx 100K, the minigun weighs approx 100Kg, the additional weaponry (and ammo) weighs at least 200Kg and the coffin (metal-lined, sufficient to withstand hundreds of bullet tracks) weighs in the region of 500Kg; http://i.stack.imgur.com/NztcT.png

Comment: @Richard I don't want to get too technical, but that is not a minigun.

Comment: @jackbnimble - an M1919A4 machine gun.

Comment: There are no technical companion books that give specs on this?

Comment: @Mazura - No, the Terminator Franchise has no technical or writers manuals to refer to. There's some "making of" books, but that's it : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_(franchise)#Other_media